# cpp socket accept but not receive on Ajax GET

Tags: c++, ajax, sockets, google-chrome, http

I am implementing Web Services in CPP program on WinCE.
I put a web server (HTTP), listenning on port 8080, and unitary tests works (using postman).

I put in a html page, a simple ajax request (GET) to get back a JSON array.

Init web server :

```
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
int optlen = 0;
struct timeval vtime;

SCK_ListenServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (SCK_ListenServerSocket < 0)
    return (WBS_Service_Unavailable_503);

// Set receive timeout
optlen = sizeof(struct timeval);

if(getsockopt(SCK_ListenServerSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &vtime, &optlen) == -1)
{
    closesocket(SCK_ListenServerSocket);
    return (WBS_Service_Unavailable_503);
}
else
{
    vtime.tv_sec = SCK_SRV_RECV_MS_TIMEOUT; // ms
    vtime.tv_usec = 0;
    if(setsockopt(SCK_ListenServerSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *) &vtime, optlen) == -1)
    {
        closesocket(SCK_ListenServerSocket);
        return (WBS_Service_Unavailable_503);
    }
}

memset((void *)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

if (bind(SCK_ListenServerSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    closesocket(SCK_ListenServerSocket);
    SCK_ListenServerSocket = -1;
    return (WBS_Service_Unavailable_503);
}

if(listen(SCK_ListenServerSocket, 1) < 0)
{
    closesocket(SCK_ListenServerSocket);
    SCK_ListenServerSocket = -1;
    return (WBS_Service_Unavailable_503);
}

return ret;
```

In a thread, that function is called :

```
accept_socket = accept(SCK_ListenServerSocket, NULL, NULL);

if(accept_socket < 0)
    n = 0;
else
{

    n = recv(accept_socket, &buffer[0], 512, 0); //Read 512 bytes

    DO THE WORK
}
```

The problem:

When I launch the web page on Chrome, the socket is opened corretly but never received. I don't know why. When I use POSTMAN it works like a charm.

Thank you for helping me.

EDIT : In that blocking socket operation, accept is called but recv is blocking. Launching a lot of request unblocks the recv, but recv response is 0 when it fails.
When I load the website on WinCE (the same target), the problem appears. When the website is loaded from my computer, and only the request is sent, no problem

Comment: Add some logging in the server. Print what's happening. Or use a debugger and set a few breakpoints, and see where it stops.

Comment: Thank you. It stops in the recv. It is like it opens the socket, and say nothing. I put a timeout to avoid blocking, but it's very strange to open a socket an say nothing.